# Are emulators isolated from the host for malware testing?

Tags: malware, android, reverse-engineering

I know that virtualization is different from emulation; I was wondering if emulation is isolated from its host and any destruction on it will not affect the host as if it were a virtual machine.

I also understand that there can be exploits that can be used to escape the emulator but I just want to know if it is isolated in general.

Comment: You've tagged "android" but haven't mentioned it in the question. Are you asking specifically about Android emulators or emulators in general?

Comment: @multithr3at3d  Well, I am specifically interested in android emulators but I would also like to know about emulators in general.

Comment: Emulators are as much isolated as virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

Barring any unknown vulnerabilities in the emulator, the general idea is that the emulated system is isolated from the host. This isolation may be reduced if you share filesystems and other resources with the emulated guest.

The level of security may also vary based on the emulator you are using. Interestingly, qemu's docs notes that it shouldn't be relied on in non-virtualization (pure emulation) mode:

> Users with non-virtualization use cases must not rely on QEMU to provide guest isolation or any security guarantees.

However, any security promises may only be true for full system emulation. There's also user-space emulation (e.g. `qemu-user`), which allows you to run programs for another architecture within you current userspace. In this case, the program has the same access as any other program you run on your system.